# KeyBoard is hiding the UITextView

Tags: uitableview, uitextview, swift4.2

I am using the following code for text field and text view. It's working properly for text field but the keyboard is still hiding the textview.

```
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {


    guard let info = notification.userInfo, let keyboardFrameValue = info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

    let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrameValue.cgRectValue
    let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.size

    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize.height + 100, right: 0.0)
    tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}


    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the library link given below

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: Thank You. But I used tableView.scrollToRow() with top position along with textview delegate and it worked.